# nslookup returns IPv4 and IPv6 of DNS and does not resolve names

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, ipv6

I have no idea what I'm doing with DNS and know enough to know the extent of my ignorance, but I'm charged with trying to troubleshoot a remote device on a remote network, both of which I do not have access to.  What appears to be happening is that on a particular network, the DHCP configured device fails to resolve names. On all other networks, things are fine, so we are left to contemplate special behavior on this particular network with respect to DHCP, and likely DNS.

Invoking `nslookup` on this remote network on a Windows host is as follows:

```
nslookup
>server ns1.[theserver].net
Default Server:  ns1.[theserver].net
Addresses:  1716:efb7::3
          125.75.227.17
> set timout=10
> set q=ns
> [bigsubdomainnamewithdashes].[thedomaininquestion].com
Server:  ns1.[theserver].net
Addresses:  1716:efb7::3
          125.75.227.17
*** ns1.[theserver].net can't find [bigsubdomainnamewithdashes].[thedomaininquestion].com:No response from server
```

but specifying the IPv4 address of `ns1.[theserver].net` alone works.

```
> server 125.75.227.17
Default Server:  [125.75.227.17]
Address:  125.75.227.17

> [bigsubdomainnamewithdashes].[thedomaininquestion].com
Server:  [125.75.227.17]
Address:  125.75.227.17

Non-authoritative answer:
[bigsubdomainnamewithdashes].[thedomaininquestion].com   canonical name = [yep a cname].com [yep a cname].com      canonical name = [yep a cname].us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

This interactive behavior of `nslookup` is surprising.  In the former instance, `nslookup` knows of a named server for which two IP address are available, IPv4 and IPv6, and it won't resolve names for which there are IPv4 addresses. In the latter instance, `nslookup` is provided an IPv4 address and does resolve the names as would be expected.

Due to my admitted ignorance, I do not want to jump to the seemingly obvious answer, so I submit the question, "What magic is nslookup performing when it gets both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address?"